Yocto packages build path
I am building images using yocto. I could see multiple folders(say all-poky-linux, poky-linux-gnueabi, armv7-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi, x86_64-linux) inside build/tmp/work/ path.
I could see that different packages are building under different directories.
Can you help me to understand where, in meta data, this configuration is set. I mean, how the folder (all-poky-linux, poky-linux-gnueabi ...) where the compilation outputs are saved is set by the meta-data of the recipe of a package?

Good question I have the same doubt. I didn't have time to understand how meta data define the output directory, so every time I look for the output in the different folders (all-poky-linux, poky-linux-gnueabi, armv7-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi, x86_64-linux).
